# When is the record locked on DB level by Salesforce?

Tags: apex, salesforce-support

Is the record locked on DB level only when we use 'For Update' in the query? Or is it locked whenever we do any Dml operation to avoid subsequent edits by other users?

Comment: it is locked every time you make a DML, FOr update is used to avoid unable to lock row error.

Comment: So what will happen when we use 'for update'? How would it ensure that record locked error won't show up?

Comment: if you use for the update, the records will be locked unit your transaction is complete and all other transactions will be put on wait. other processes can wait for max up to 10 secs.

Comment: I think whatever you said is little confusing.